# Cannot change width of a custom scrollbar on hover using ::-webkit-scrollbar:hover

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a custom scrollbar to change its width when cursor is getting close to it. (it's for an Electron app, so it only need to work in Chrome).

I don't know how to trigger the width change while the cursor is still a few px away from it, so I'm just specifying a different width on `:hover`:

#### Code

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {    
  background-color: lightGrey;
  width: 18px;
} 


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

All the code (with Vue framework):
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVYQvq

Here's just a simple HTML version:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQxGZX

---

### Problem

As you can see from the codepen, it changes color on hover but not the width.

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (Build oficial) (64 bits) and working good ( also width change )

Comment: @MTK could you tell me what you did? I just tried adding that code in a simple HTML with just 1 div of text (instead of Electron app), opened it in Chrome and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry for mi english. So I have oppened your codepen link in mi chrome 63 and if i change in your css `::-webkit-scrollbar` ... the `width` property. That work as espected ... the scrollbar width change correctly

Comment: Ok sorry ... You talk about hover ... So at hover ... not work also in chrome 63

Comment: It seem that `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover` only work on html element scrollbar but not on window scrollbar see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3ZR/1/

Comment: @MTK strange enough this one also doesn't work for me, it only works when you hover over the 1st pixel from the right side off the scroll bar. That is strange the way it works. Thanks for looking into it though

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any update on the solution .

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit late, however I was able to solve this issue, not sure if its efficient or not.

```
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    background: WhiteSmoke;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 20px;
    background: WhiteSmoke;
}
```

the code above seems to need both, this is how I got it to work on electron.

Hope it helps anyone.